# How can I stop windows from rattling?

Tags: windows

My windows are probably original, from 1978. They are normal windows plus storm windows. The storm windows rattle like crazy in the wind. There's a lot of wind here in Boulder, Colorado. What's a good way to keep them from rattling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to figure out what exactly is rattling. Is the storm window rattling against the normal window, or is it parts of the storm window rattling against each other?

Without a picture to show exactly what's loose, my general suggestions are:

- Tighten up any screws on the storm window--you can use some blue loctite on them if you want to prevent them from loosening up again.
- add foam weather stripping around the perimeter of the storm window where it contacts the normal window or house. This should take up the slack that allows it to rattle and make it more effective as well.
- for any other gaps you can try wedging in some vinyl gasket weather stripping:

[image: vinyl gasket weather stripping]

Comment: Thanks Brad. I think they're just rattling inside their frames. I'll try the weather stripping.